# Can I use BitLocker to encrypt my main SSD without a CMOS battery?

Tags: bitlocker

I removed my CMOS battery because it was dead and the laptop wouldn't start. I have no ability to purchase a new one, but the laptop works properly without it.

Can I enable BitLocker on my hard drive without it? or will is mess up everything?

I've searched a lot and I couldn't find a specific answer. The reason I'm asking is because I found some people having a problem booting into Windows after removing the CMOS battery (when already using BitLocker).

Comment: Why can't you buy a new battery?

Comment: because this is more of a Windows operational question than a security question, I'm migrating

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how Bitlocker would depend on any information that is lost when the CMOS battery is removed. However, it might be possible if not likely that Bitlocker makes some kind of time checking refusing to boot the system if the hardware clock has an "unplausible" value. Since the hardware clock is reset if the system is completely without power (i.e. no standby, no CMOS battery) you may have to set the clock before being able to boot a Bitlocker secured system.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas - I think I'll just wait until I move back to the West and buy a CMOS battery.